# Can I open the java console programatically from within an applet?

Tags: java

We have a java applet we are running inside our company, but due to "reasons" the java consoles icon (in the tray) is deactivated by default in the java control panel.

Whenever a user has a problem we cannot really help him since there seems to be no way to open the java console afterwards. Activating it in the java control panel only activates it for newly opened java applets.

So is there any way to open the java console programmatically from within our own java code?

Searching for this problem only gives me lots and lots of hits for opening a normal cmd/bash console.

Comment: "_Searching for this problem only gives me lots and lots of hits for opening a normal cmd/bash console._" Why can't you just substitute the console.exe that you want for the cmd.exe or whatever in those examples?

Comment: It's no special executable I want to show, it's the console which is a part of the running applets java.exe. https://pasteboard.co/HtdC2bR.png